# How can these be the weights of the adjoint representation?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

This is perhaps a stupid question. We consider $G =\text{SU}(3)$ and $\pi : G \to \textrm{GL}(\mathfrak{g})$ the adjoint representation that sends $g \in G$ to $Ad_g$ that acts on the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ be the following formula. For $X \in \mathfrak{g}$, 
$$Ad_g(X) = gXg^{-1}.$$

Now I am trying to find the weight vectors for this representation. I get that they are the elementary matrices $E_{ij}$ but there is one problem: These $E_{ij}$ ***technically don't live in $\mathfrak{g}$***! This is because an elementary matrix $E_{ij}$ does not satisfy the relation $X + X^\ast = 0$. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Since you are not considering the action of the full $SL(n)$, you should get some additional weight vectors which actually do lie in the Lie algebra.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I don't understand what you mean. At this point, by weight vector I mean the following. We consider the standard torus $T$ of $G$. Restricting $\text{Ad}$ to $T$, this should decompose into a direct sum of one dimensional representations. A weight is thus just an eigenvalue.

Comment: To conclude that those ones are all the weight vectors, you need that you have an action of all of $SL(3)$ rather than just an action of $SU(3)$. Since you have a smaller group acting, you get some extra weight vectors, and these should indeed be in the Lie algebra.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft There is a problem now in that the $E_{ij}$ are not elements of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$. How can they be weight vectors then?

Comment: Obviously they can't. But there should be some other vectors which are also weight vectors and are indeed elements in that Lie algebra. You should redo your calculations to check this.

Comment: (When I say "also", I mean when we consider the action on the full Lie algebra $gl(n)$ and consider $su(n)$ as a subalgebra of this).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Right. At the moment I can't seem to find any obvious candidates.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think the problem at the moment is that $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ is only a real Lie algebra. I think perhaps we want to look at the adjoint representation on  complexification which is $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\Bbb{C})$. Then the $E_{ij}$ are indeed weight vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, the issue is that eigenvectors (weight vectors) often lie only in the *complexified* Lie algebra. Here, a useful, compatible model of the complexification of $\frak su$$(n)$ is $\frak sl$$(n,\mathbb C)$, making the relevance of @TobiasKildetoft's comments perhaps clearer. Indeed, the question does turn into asking about the action of the complexified algebra on itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was trying to do Bump exercise 24.1 and he just said "adjoint representation of $\text{SU}(3)$ acting on the eight dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $\text{SU}(3)$. I suppose by that he meant "complexification of Lie algebra of $\text{SU}(3)$."

Comment: Yes, it _must_ be on the complexification.